# Square: Call to undefined function charge

Tags: square-connect

Reading the [installation instructions for Square's SDK](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk) I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function charge() in
>   D:......\square\1.php on line 28

I added the missing `$access_token` though am unsure how to proceed? How do I fix the missing charge function bug?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$access_token = 'sandbox-abcdefghijkl_mnopqrstivwxyzzz';
# setup authorization
\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
# create an instance of the Transaction API class
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$location_id = 'CBASEEum0KeFu_h-4VA4OWaV3F8gAQ';
$nonce = 'CBA15363g28251525625624455255A';

$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);

try {
  $result = $transactions_api-charge($location_id, $request_body);
  print_r($result);
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Exception when calling TransactionApi->charge:";
  var_dump($e->getResponseBody());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy and paste this from somewhere?

```
$transactions_api-charge
```

Should be

```
$transactions_api->charge
```

Comment: Worked! Yes, copied from the SDK installation instructions. I'll try to make a GIT edit suggestion there (not sure how open they are to corrections). I'm moving along to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479573/square-card-nonce-not-found-in-this-sandbox-application-environment and I appreciate your help!

Comment: I opened a pull request for you: https://github.com/square/connect-api-specification/pull/83

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate your help! When I finally get this all working I'll post what worked for me on my blog in totality.

Comment: Can you share the full link or source code as I am trying to integrate , but i get request not authorised error, can you help ??

Comment: You can see a full example here https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/README.md