# Square: Card nonce not found in this `sandbox` application environment

Tags: square-connect

I am receiving the following error when trying to run the demonstration from the Square SDK:

> Card nonce not found in this `sandbox` application environment. Please
>   ensure an application ID belonging to the same environment is used for
>   the SqPaymentForm.

When I `echo '<pre>';print_r($request_body); echo '</pre>';` I receive the following:

```
Array
(
 [card_nonce] => 123456789098765432123456789
 [amount_money] => Array
 (
  [amount] => 100
  [currency] => USD
 )

 [idempotency_key] => 59cd807f20ce2
)
```

It appears that the nonce *is* defined. I just ran last night's code with my own credit card for testing purposes and am using the sandbox location *and* token. How do I resolve this problem?

The full PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$access_token = 'sandbox-abcdef-ghi-j_klmnopqrstuvwxyz';
# setup authorization
\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
# create an instance of the Transaction API class
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$location_id = '0987654321098_7654321098765432';
$nonce = '123456789012345678901234567';

$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 10,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);

echo '<pre>';print_r($request_body); echo '</pre>';

try {
  $result = $transactions_api->charge($location_id, $request_body);
  print_r($result);
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Exception when calling TransactionApi->charge:";
  var_dump($e->getResponseBody());
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably created the nonce with a different account. Try making a new nonce with your sandbox application id.

Comment: @tristansokol I'll re-verify that right now...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the [test cases](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2) that Square proposes at first and then add to your platform. The issue here is that you must generate the `card_nonce` attribute from `SqPaymentForm` in the view, just as the [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) say:

> A nonce generated from the SqPaymentForm that represents the card to
>   charge. The application that provides a nonce to this endpoint must be
>   the same application that generated the nonce with the SqPaymentForm.
>   Otherwise, the nonce is invalid.